# Vue3 - How do I pass through a variable name on a @click function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a button that activates the raiseStat() function. I want to pass through the name of an existing variable so that a function can then modify that specific variable.

The button:

```
<button @click="raiseStat(health)">Add</button>
```

The data I want to modify:

```
data(){
    return{
        health: 1,
    }
},
```

The function:

```
 methods: {
    raiseStat(statName){
      statName++
    },

},
```

When I console.log the variable within the function it says '1' which makes sense, I'm passing through the value of the variable, not the name.

So how would I refer to the name of this variable rather than the value?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare stats as object and then access to the 'health' key :

```
<button @click="raiseStat('health')">Add</button>
```

```
data(){
    return{
        health: 1,
    }
},
methods: {
    raiseStat(statName){
      this[statName] += 1
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SIHEM ! I actually get an error clicking the button after updating this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'health')

Comment: In your code you have `health` not `stats.health` so it would be `this[statName]` instead I'm guessing.

Comment: @Peter that's right, changing it to this[statName] worked. Thanks guys

Comment: So it should work, look at the data i've changed the declaration of 'health' to be included inside an object called 'stats', are you sure to access the 'stats[statName]' and not directly 'this[statName]'